# How to make longtable with a very long text?

Tags: longtable, music

I want to make a `longtable` out of this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R5sqETvhat16r2xkvhGDh64LkOi12CE_/view?usp=sharing).

For starters, I've tried to do this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\usepackage{tabto}
\newenvironment{tabs}[1]
{\TabPositions{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable}  
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{musicography}

\begin{document}
\begin{small}
    \begin{longtable}{|c|l|l|r|}
        \caption{Hasil pengujian \textit{threshold} pada lagu Twinkle-Twinkle Little Star di model pertama}
        \label{tab:dtw-thres-twinkle}\\     
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{\textbf{No}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\textit{Unique pitch}}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\textit{Pitch class}}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\textit{Distance}}} \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        
        \textbf{1} & [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58] & [A$\sharp$2 / B$\flat$2, B2, C3, C$\sharp$3 / D$\flat$3, D3, D$\sharp$3 / E$\flat$3, E3, F3, F$\sharp$3 / G$\flat$3, G3, G$\sharp$3 / A$\flat$3, A3, A$\sharp$3 / B$\flat$3] & 2 \bigstrut\\
        
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{small}
\begin{document}
```

The resulting output is not very pleasant, as it goes out of the margin (you can ignore the text above the table). This is the sample output opened from Adobe Reader.
[image: sample output]

What can I do to modify my table to fit in my page nicely?

Comment: How or where is `\bigstrut` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you load the `xltabular` package, as it lets you combine the features of the `longtable` (table that can span multiple pages) and `tabularx` (allow automatic linebreaks, calculate column widths automatically) environments.

I would also dispense with putting `\flat` and `\sharp` in math mode. Next, I'd give the table a much more open "look" by (a) getting rid of all vertical rules and (b) omitting most horizontal rules. For the few remaining horizontal rules, I'd use the macros of the `booktabs` packages -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\addlinespace`, and `\bottomrule` -- instead of `\hline`. Finally, I'd do away with the unnecessary `\makeatother` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\usepackage{musicography}

\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\bfseries}l L L r @{}}

\caption{Hasil pengujian \textit{threshold} pada lagu 
         Twinkle-Twinkle Little Star di model pertama}
\label{tab:dtw-thres-twinkle} \\
\toprule
No & \textbf{Unique pitch} & \textbf{Pitch class} & \textbf{Distance} \\
\midrule    
\endhead

\midrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


1 & 0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58   
& A\sharp2 / B\flat2, B2, C3, C\sharp3 / D\flat3, D3, D\sharp3 / E\flat3, E3, F3, F\sharp3 / G\flat3, G3, G\sharp3 / A\flat3, A3, A\sharp3 / B\flat3    
& 2 \\ \addlinespace
2 & 0, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57   
& G\sharp2 / A\flat2, A2, A\sharp2 / B\flat2, B2, C3, C\sharp3 / D\flat3, D3, D\sharp3 / E\flat3, E3, F3, F\sharp3 / G\flat3, G3, G\sharp3 / A\flat3, A3    
& 521 \\ \addlinespace
3 & 0, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59   
& C3, C\sharp3 / D\flat3, D3, D\sharp3 / E\flat3, E3, F3, F\sharp3 / G\flat3, G3, G\sharp3 / A\flat3, A3, A\sharp3 / B\flat3, B3    
& 550 \\ \addlinespace
4 & 0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55   
& A\sharp2 / B\flat2, B2, C3, C\sharp3 / D\flat3, D3, D\sharp3 / E\flat3, E3, F3, F\sharp3 / G\flat3, G3    
& 637 \\ 

\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I try your solution, the ```pitch-class``` column is not auto-fit-content. It again goes away from the column margin.

Comment: @DionisiusPratama - Your experience appears to be quite different from mine; for sure, the table shown abobe fits *exactly* inside the text block. Please clarify what exactly you're doing. In particular, please state whether you use the definition of the L column type I use above. A remark: It's *not* the same as in your query.

Comment: Don't worry, I found my mistake. I didn't use the ```L``` column type that you gave. Already done now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the width of the table column. For this, you need to use the `array` package. Have a look here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Table caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|m{0.4\textwidth}|m{0.4\textwidth}|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{No} & \textbf{\textit{Unique pitch}} & \textit{\textbf{Pitch Class}} & \textbf{\textit{Distance}} \\ \hline
        \textbf{1} & [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58] & [A$\sharp$2 / B$\flat$2, B2, C3, C$\sharp$3 / D$\flat$3, D3, D$\sharp$3 / E$\flat$3, E3, F3, F$\sharp$3 / G$\flat$3, G3, G$\sharp$3 / A$\flat$3, A3, A$\sharp$3 / B$\flat$3] & 2 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:lab}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This will give you the following output:
[image]

Comment: One of the OP's objectives is to be able to create a table that spans more than one page. How does your code help achieve this objective?

Comment: Yes, I can do it now. Thank you for the suggestion. But, by using ```\begin{table}[htbp]``` package, I won't be able to spans more than one page. Maybe, you can change the package by using ```longtable``` or ```xltabular```.